# Fetch API - storing a html file in a variable then query the variable contents

Tags: javascript, fetch

Pretty novice to Javascript. So any help would be great.

I'm using the fetch to retrieve html from a search like below:

```
var downloadHtml;
fetch(
  'https://cors- 
anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://www.youtube.com/results? 
search_query=A+Song'
)
  .then(r => r.text())
  .then(data => (downloadHTML = data))
```

Is it then possible to call another function or perform matches on the downloaded content. So in the method below if you was to execute this on the basepage of the Url in question it would return the list on all the video tags in question.

```
let GetSongLinks = () => {
var songs = []
let count = document.querySelectorAll('a#video-title.yt- 
simple-endpoint.style-scope.ytd-video-renderer').length;

const baseUrl = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v='

for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {

    let baseSong = document.querySelectorAll
    ('a#video-title.yt-simple-endpoint.style-scope.ytd-video- 
     renderer')[i].innerText

    let songId = document.querySelectorAll
    ('a#video-title.yt-simple-endpoint.style-scope.ytd-video- 
    renderer'
    )[i].data.watchEndpoint.videoId

    console.log(songs.push( baseSong + ' - ' + baseUrl +  songId))
  }
}
```

Is it possible to either call this function after the promise has been returned and pass data to the function to query these? Or is there a way to scrape the downloadHtml into the variable to find these values? Or even if this is possible? or not? Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Consider using indentation when writing code. It'll make reading and debugging it much easier.

Comment: Sorry it was just my input when writing the question.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it you can definitely invoke a cleaning method like that inside `.then()`. It comes down to style. Have the method take in `data`, and invoke it in your second `.then()`.

There could be ways to scrape your data. It's hard without seeing the data. Consider posting a snippet of the data you get back.